# UICollectionView With Variable Cells Displaying Them Weirdly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I want to have cells that are always half the height of the display and sometimes half of the width but sometimes 1/4th the width. In the picture below I have drawn what the UICollectionView is displaying. In landscape I am telling it to display a 1/4th width cell and then a half cell and then another 1/4th and that repeats again. In theory there should be 6 cells on the screen, but the cells end up all scattered. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If I have every cell one size it works fine, just with different sizes this happens.

This is what happens: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2G33.jpg]

This is what I want to happen: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmY0N.jpg]

Heres my code for setting up the layout and altering the individual cell sizes:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([bigCells containsObject: indexPath.row]) {
        return CGSizeMake((CollectionView.frame.size.width/2), (CollectionView.frame.size.height/2));
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake((CollectionView.frame.size.width/4), (CollectionView.frame.size.height/2));
    }
}

- (void)prepareLayout {
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake((self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2), (self.collectionView.frame.size.height/2));

    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is bigCells an array of indexPaths?

Comment: The `containsObject:` method sounds like it takes an object reference as its argument, but `-[NSIndexPath row]` returns an `NSInteger`, which is a primitive type, not an object reference.  You should be getting at least a warning, if not a compiler error, on that line, and it should crash at runtime.  Or have you done something special to make it work with plain integers?

Comment: In fact, are you sure the app is even calling your `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method?  Have you put an `NSLog` or a breakpoint in it to verify that the app is calling it?

Comment: I am sure the app is calling this hence I get the variable cell size and that code works in the sense that it does produce the cells with the sizes I want, they are just laid out weirdly.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?